# To know the Suspended users from Stackoverflow and their suspension days

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

After reading this [meta stackExchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114687/reputation-distribution-by-location), is there any possibility to list out all the suspended users from StackOverflow and their suspension days?